# Embedding YouTube videos on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, youtube

I have embedded a YouTube clip on a webpage:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
<iframe id="theframe" width="400" height="325" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/MYYOUTUBECLIP" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class=""></iframe>
```

This works fine in Chrome and FireFox and displays as an embedded video in the webpage. However, if viewed on Internet Explorer (10 or 11) then when the user tries to view that page the browser redirects to youtube and then fails to load.

What is going on here? Many thanks...

Comment: IE.this is what's going on here

Comment: I suspect its a problem with Flash Player. Since YouTube uses HTML5 for Chrome and Firefox, and other "Modern" browsers. IE still has a lot of catching up to do regarding HTML5, so therefore: YouTube may use Flash as a fallback to play videos in IE. Check that you have it installed and enabled in the addons-manager. Also, check that you don't view the page in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So the actual answer to my problem is that on some of the embedded links they were:

```
<iframe id="theframe" width="400" height="325" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/MYYOUTUBECLIP" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class=""></iframe>
```

while some were:

```
<iframe id="theframe" width="400" height="325" src="http:////www.youtube.com/embed/MYYOUTUBECLIP" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class=""></iframe>
```

Notice the difference? The second one has "http:////www..." which is two too many '/'. It appears that Internet Explorers don't like this so try and send you off to the url. One of those quirky things, eh...

Answer (score 0):

The Best Possible answer can be, If you have ever noticed To play YouTube videos we need a plash player, and if you ever download flash player from sites like filehippo you will see that there are two version of it 
1st, IE 
2nd Non-IE. 
The clients may be missing IE version of flash player.
try installing IE flash player and try again. Good Luck.

Try this code:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/MYYOUTUBECLIP" width="400" height="325">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/embed/MYYOUTUBECLIP" />
</object>
```